# Doctest not recognizing __future__.division

Tags: python, future, division, doctest

I have the following doctest written `x.doctest`:

```
This is something:

    >>> x = 3 + 4

foo bar something else:

    >>> from __future__ import division
    >>> y = 15
    >>> z = int('24')
    >>> m = z / y
    >>> print (m)
    1.6
```

But when I ran `python -m doctest x.doctest` on python 2.7.11, the doctest didn't recognize `from __future__ import division`:

```
**********************************************************************
File "x.doctest", line 11, in x.doctest
Failed example:
    print (m)
Expected:
    1.6
Got:
    1
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   6 in x.doctest
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Even when I shifted the future import statement to the first line:

```
This is something:

    >>> from __future__ import division
    >>> x = 3 + 4

foo bar something else:

    >>> y = 15
    >>> z = int('24')
    >>> m = z / y
    >>> print (m)
    1.6
```

The doctest still fails:

```
**********************************************************************
File "x.doctest", line 11, in x.doctest
Failed example:
    print (m)
Expected:
    1.6
Got:
    1
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   6 in x.doctest
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

**Why is that so and how can I resolve this?**

**Is there a flag / option for doctest that asks ensures that `from __future__ import division` is recognized?**

Note: I could just force the check on `print (int(m))` or `y = 15.` and the doctest will pass but that is not that desirable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doctests run each line *in isolation* through the Python compiler. This means that any compiler flags specified with a `from __future__ import ..` statement *in the doctest itself* is useless in a doctest.

However, you *can* add names from the real [`__future__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html) to your doctest globals. If you *don't* use the `from __future__ import <name>` format but use `import __future__` instead, you import that actual module, and can add references to the objects it defines to the doctest `globs` or `extraglobs` dictionaries:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     import doctest
     import __future__
     doctest.testmod(extraglobs={'division': __future__.division})
```

The `DocTestRunner` will then set the right compiler flags for you when compiling individual lines from these.

Demo:

```
>>> import doctest
>>> import __future__
>>> import sys
>>> def foo():
...     """
...     >>> 1 / 2
...     0.5
...     """
...
>>> doctest.testmod(sys.modules['__main__'])
**********************************************************************
File "__main__", line 3, in __main__.foo
Failed example:
    1 / 2
Expected:
    0.5
Got:
    0
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   1 in __main__.foo
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
TestResults(failed=1, attempted=1)
>>> doctest.testmod(sys.modules['__main__'], extraglobs={'division': __future__.division})
TestResults(failed=0, attempted=1)
```

Comment: Just to confirm some facts, the `if __name__ == 'main':` trick could only work in a `x.py` file and not a `x.doctest`, is that right?

Comment: @alvas: I'm not familiar with `.doctest` files. I suspect your project loads those explicitly somewhere with a `DocFileSuite()` instance; set the globals on *that*.

Comment: @alvas: the code that loads those files could itself do some parsing logic to add compile flags to the globals based on file contents, of course.

Comment: Thanks Martijn for the explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `-Q` for the Python interpreter. Set it to `new`:

```
python -Qnew -m doctest x.doctest
```

Get help on Python commandline options with:

```
python -h
```

Selected output:

> -Q arg : division options: -Qold (default), -Qwarn, -Qwarnall, -Qnew

More help details [here](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-Q).

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link to the `-Q` documentation? Is there a way to do it with a `#doctest: ` comment within the `x.doctest` file?

Comment: Added a help link. I am not aware any `#doctest:` directives for this. On Unix.based systems, you could add a shebang to your file: `#!/usr/bin/env python -Qnew -m doctest` and execute with `./x.doctest`.

Comment: `-Qnew` is a global change, though, affecting even code that wasn't supposed to be using true division. The [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) that introduced true divison says `-Qnew` is only intended for educational contexts where the instructors want true division but don't want the students to have to include `from __future__ import division` in all their code.