# How can I make doctests triggered by pytest ignore unicode prefix `u'...'` of strings?

Tags: python-2.7, unicode, pytest, doctest

I want my code to work in Python 2 and 3. I use doctests and

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Is there a flag I can set / a plugin which makes it ignore that Python 2 has the `u` prefix for unicode strings?

### Example

One test that works in Python 3, but fails in Python 2:

```
Expected:
    'Me \\& you.'
Got:
    u'Me \\& you.'
```

### Minimal example

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals


def foo():
    """

    Returns
    -------
    unicode - for Python 2 and Python 3

    Examples
    --------
    >>> foo()
    'bar'
    """
    return 'bar'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: In this case the problem is likely not "the `u` prefix", it's that `"..."` is a different ***type*** than `u"..."`. The comparison fails because you're testing a `str` value against a `unicode` value.

Comment: As it also fails for `u"Me \\& you."` instead of `u'Me \\& you.'` I am pretty sure doctests compares the strings directly.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example to reproduce this problem.

Comment: Well, `unicode_literals` means that implicitly all literals are `u''` literals. I suppose that doesn't apply to doctest, since the value written in the docstring isn't a literal (it's a literal in a literal) and doctest doesn't consider the imported `unicode_literals`. If you declare the expected value as `u'bar'` it works.

Comment: @deceze No, it doesn't work to declare the expected value as `u'bar'`. The problem is that I want it to run on Python 2 and 3 as I wrote in the first sentence of my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using doctest directly, you can override the OutputChecker as per Dirkjan Ochtman's blog post [Single-source Python 2/3 doctests](https://dirkjan.ochtman.nl/writing/2014/07/06/single-source-python-23-doctests.html):

```
class Py23DocChecker(doctest.OutputChecker):
  def check_output(self, want, got, optionflags):
    if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
      want = re.sub("u'(.*?)'", "'\\1'", want)
      want = re.sub('u"(.*?)"', '"\\1"', want)
    return doctest.OutputChecker.check_output(self, want, got, optionflags)

doctest.DocTestSuite(mod, checker=Py23DocChecker())
```

If you're using py.test, you can specify `doctest_optionflags = ALLOW_UNICODE` in pytest.ini. See https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/doctest.html